# Check if there are similar rows in a table

Tags: select

As a Rookie in SQL I have a problem creating a query.

Here is the problem : I would like to check on a table if there are lines that share the same DATES.

For example I would like to know if in TABLE A, there are cases like this :

```
ID | LIB | START_DATE | END_DATE
01 | A1  | 01-01-2016 | 05-03-2016
02 | A2  | 03-03-2016 | 05-06-2016
```

Those lines are SURVEYS and I would like to know if an admin created a survey that is starting during an other survey. I did some searches on AUTO JOIN but this wasn't really what I was looking for.

My case is a bit more complicated but I will find out myself if you explain  how to proceed on this simple case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be something like:

```
select   s1.id, s2.id
from     surveys s1, surveys s2
where    (s2.start_date between s1.start_date and s1.end_date
or        s2.end_date   between s1.start_date and s1.end_date)
and      s1.id!=s2.id;
```

This fetches you the `ID`s where the `START_DATE` or `END_DATE` (of `s2`) is in the period of another `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` (`s1`).

Comment: Is there a way to not having in results 25, 52 when you already have 52, 25 ?

Comment: @JulienS - this is a new question. Ask it as such.

Answer (score 2):

this would be exact

```
select min(id), max(id)  
from table 
group by start_da, end_date 
having count(*) > 1
```

start in

```
select t1.*, t2*
from table t1 
join table t2
      on t1.startdate between t2.startdate and t2.end_date
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the first query returns nothing and the second one return every surveys.

Comment: Then every survey satisfies t1.startdate between t2.startdate and t2.end_date     It is exactly the stated question and the same as the answer you accepted.   You must have keyed it in wrong.

Comment: I'll double check, anyway thank you for your help :)